Как сравнивать строки без учета регистра в С++?
Необходимо проверить строку, в данном случае проверка на "да". Как можно сравнивать строку без учета регистра, чтобы была возможность писать, как: "Да", "ДА" и т.п. Без использования (sim == 'Да' || sim == 'ДА').
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    string sim;
    cout << "Да или нет?" << endl;
    cin >> sim;

    if (sim =="Да") 
    cout << "Хорошо" << endl;
    else cout << "Плохо";

    return 0 ; 
}


Вы можете сравнить строки по длине, плюс использовать std::equal с использованием std::tolower, который приведет строки к нижнему регистру. Например, вот так:
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

bool stringCompare(const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2) 
{
    return str1.size() == str2.size() && std::equal(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str2.begin(), [](unsigned char c1, unsigned char c2)
    {
        return std::tolower(c1) == std::tolower(c2);
    });
}

Можно даже проще:
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>


bool stringCompare(const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2) 
{
    if (str1.size() != str2.size()) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str1.size(); ++i) 
    {
        if (std::tolower(str1[i]) != std::tolower(str2[i])) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

Ну, и в main() через цикл if прогнать. Если true вернет, то значит все ок.
UPD
Тогда в первом случае код будет выглядеть так:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

bool stringCompare(const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2) 
{
    return str1.size() == str2.size() && std::equal(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str2.begin(), [](unsigned char c1, unsigned char c2)
    {
        return std::tolower(c1) == std::tolower(c2);
    });
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    string sim;
    cout << "Да или нет?" << endl;
    cin >> sim;

    if (stringCompare(sim, "Да")) 
    {
        cout << "Хорошо" << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Плохо" << endl;
    }

    return 0; 
}

Во втором так:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

bool stringCompare(const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2) 
{
    if (str1.size() != str2.size()) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str1.size(); ++i) 
    {
        if (std::tolower(str1[i]) != std::tolower(str2[i])) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    string sim;
    cout << "Да или нет?" << endl;
    cin >> sim;

    if (stringCompare(sim, "Да")) 
    {
        cout << "Хорошо" << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Плохо" << endl;
    }

    return 0; 
}

Можете вообще использовать уже написанную библотечную stricmp():
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>  // <--- библиотека для нее 

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    string sim;
    cout << "Да или нет?" << endl;
    cin >> sim;

    
    if (_stricmp(sim.c_str(), "Да") == 0) 
    {
        cout << "Хорошо" << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Плохо" << endl;
    }

    return 0; 
}

Учтите, что в данном методе необходимо будет перевести строку в, так называемую, C-строку (c_str()) для получения указателя на массив символов (по другому с железкой никак). Можете подробнее почитать тут

Можно конкретнее на моем примере?

Вам бы попрактиковать с функциями ;)

спасибо, хорошо
